# Sales current Month vs Previous in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to calculate Sales current month vs previous month by client.

expected output for Sales Diff column:

| Date | Client | Sales | Sales Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06 | A | 100 | 100 |
| 2022-06 | B | 250 | 250 |
| 2022-07 | A | 150 | 50 |
| 2022-07 | B | 310 | 60 |

I tried below code but I'm getting NaN instead of the current Sales value when client first purchase

```
df['Diff'] =  df.groupby('Client')['Sales'].diff()
```

| Date | Client | Sales | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06 | A | 100 | NaN |
| 2022-06 | B | 250 | NaN |
| 2022-07 | A | 150 | 50 |
| 2022-07 | B | 310 | 60 |

Comment: There's just no value to take the `diff` from, why not add another row for each customer where you start from 0 sales?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to fill the `NaN` with the value the `Client` starts with.
This should work:

```
df['Diff'] = df.groupby('Client')['Sales'].diff().fillna(df['Sales'])
```

```
      Date Client  Sales   Diff
0  2022-06      A    100  100.0
1  2022-06      B    250  250.0
2  2022-07      A    150   50.0
3  2022-07      B    310   60.0
```